# Java IDL for gRPC / protobuf (Protocl Buffers)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, pojo, idl, grpc

Is it possible to define Protocol Buffers using Java?

That is instead of

```
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}
```

I would like to have

```
public interface Greeter {
    @Grpc
    HelloReply sayHello (HelloRequest req);

}

@GrpcMessage()
public class HelloReply{
    @GrpcField(1)
    string name;
}
```

That is annotation like Hibernate/JPA over my POJO, instead of heaps of generated code.

I only could find Protocol Buffers Dynamic Schema https://github.com/os72/protobuf-dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at protostuff: https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff
It supports what you want for protobuf (although not for grpc, perhaps it can be enhanced)

Comment: Yes, that is half-answer, but nice to know http://www.protostuff.io/documentation/runtime-schema/ and http://www.protostuff.io/documentation/maven-plugin/